# Angular sidenav seems to refresh on each link clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

The initial view is a login component.  Once the user logs in, they are redirected to "home" component.  Home component has a top toolbar, along with a sidenav.  The sidenav contains links the user can click on.  When clicking the links, the sidenav seems to not fully complete the "highlight" animation, but seems to refresh the whole page. This is illustrated in the StackBlitz example, when clicking between the two links, you can see animation stops/refreshes.  The initial view with button is setup to mimic the login redirect.  Thanks for any input.

Link to StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bamdb4?file=src/app/home/home.component.html

Comment: This is interesting, I see what you are saying, but I'm not seeing the same behavior on the stackblitz

Comment: Hmm, i am seeing it on my end.  When you click a link/tab, the angular animation should play out smoothly.  However, in this case it doesn't.  Seems to get interrupted. You can see it fully animate, if your are already on that link, and press it again.  But clicking off of that link will show the error.  If that makes sense :)

Comment: What's the browser in which you are seeing the issue?

Comment: Chrome Version 91.0.4472.124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that when you navigate you replace the entire page. You can easily debug this if you put a simple statement in `home.component.ts` file something like:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('jancsi ' + Math.random());
  }
```

if you open the Console each time you navigate, you will see new entry.

The way you setup the routing causes this as you have top level routes for: `dashboard` and `userprofile`

Try setting it up like this (true child routes of home) route:

```
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,

    children: [
      {
        path: 'userprofile',
        component: UserProfileComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      }
    ]
  },
```

Also change the routerLink (remove the `/` slash) to look like this:

```
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="dashboard">First Component</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="userprofile">Second Component</a>
```

animation will not be interrupted and there will be no new `ngOnInit` call on `HomeComponent`

Check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mqgmmn?file=src%2Froutes.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much, this resolved the issue.  I did do the console output just to see how many times oninit() gets called, and did notice that it was called multiple times.  Just wasn't sure as to how to solve it.  Looks like setting up children components properly fixes the issue.  Thank you so much.